# Connecting to remote task manager has failed. This might indicate that the remote task manager has been lost

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have created a flink standalone cluster with 1 job manager and 2 taskmanager.
When a batch task/job is submitted, one of the task manager is throwing the below error.  flink dashboard shows both task managers actvive. Sample wordcount program works.

```
java.io.IOException: Connecting the channel failed: Connecting to remote task manager + 'hostname/127.0.0.1:46537' has failed. This might indicate that the remote task manager has been lost.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory$ConnectingChannel.waitForChannel(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:197)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory$ConnectingChannel.access$000(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory.createPartitionRequestClient(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyConnectionManager.createPartitionRequestClient(NettyConnectionManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.RemoteInputChannel.requestSubpartition(RemoteInputChannel.java:156)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate.requestPartitions(SingleInputGate.java:480)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate.getNextBufferOrEvent(SingleInputGate.java:502)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.reader.AbstractRecordReader.getNextRecord(AbstractRecordReader.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.reader.MutableRecordReader.next(MutableRecordReader.java:42)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.ReaderIterator.next(ReaderIterator.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.NoOpDriver.run(NoOpDriver.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:490)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Connecting to remote task manager + 'hostname/127.0.0.1:46537' has failed. This might indicate that the remote task manager has been lost.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory$ConnectingChannel.operationComplete(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:220)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientFactory$ConnectingChannel.operationComplete(PartitionRequestClientFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: ekablr-ca-s010/127.0.0.1:46537
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to check for:

- Is something in your job slowing down the TaskManager so much that it can't answer requests before they time out? Watch CPU usage on the machine running the TaskManager for this one.
- Is the TaskManager really still active (i.e. still sending heartbeats that you can see live updating in the TaskManager section of the dashboard) or has the JobManager just not given up on it enough to mark it dead? It's possible for your job to kill the TaskManager it's running on, but I've usually only seen it with native code running through JNI or some other direct memory manipulation type of stuff.